# Practice Problem Fundamental Group of 7-figured polygon

Tags: algebraic-topology

The question is from Munkres:  Consider the space $X$ obtained from a seven-sided polygonal region by means of the labelling scheme $abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$.  Show that the fundamental group of $X$ is the free product of two cyclic groups.  The solution given says that the least normal subgroup $N$ is generated by $b^{-1}a^{-1}abaaa = a^3$.  Can someone explain this?

Comment: If no one can answer this, can someone explain an alternative way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Seifert–van Kampen theorem, you need to mod out the normal subgroup $N$ generated by $abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$. But $(ab)aaa(ab)^{-1}=abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$. Hence $N$ is also generated by $a^3$.

Hence $\pi(X)=\mathbb{Z_3} * \mathbb{Z}$.